# How to get .AAR file from gradle dependency?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, aar

Is it possible to get the .AAR file from the following gradle link or any gradle link?

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can find the link to download the arr here https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmaterialdrawer

By searching the package name in the the mavencentral repo where this is being hosted, you can directly download the AAR.